# Убрать ApplicationMenu в Ribbon

Tags: wpf, xaml

Пытаюсь разобраться в RibbonWindow. Возможно ли из ленты убрать или спрятать ApplicationMenu и как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте в ваш риббон следующий код:

```
<Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
    <RibbonApplicationMenu Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
```

Результат:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Пробовали писать так?

```
   <r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
      <r:RibbonApplicationMenu Visibility="Collapsed"/>
   </r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
```